# how to progressive rendering a mesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, mesh

I have a bezier curve on which I draw a mesh. I want to render it progressively. You can see the final result on this video: 
https://youtu.be/J8oyxfL5IeU

For achieve this result I build the mesh vertex dynamically but I think that this isn't the best method. Is there a better way to do this without rebuild the mesh? For example using a shader or uv map? Unfortunately I am not practical of this subjects.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious is indeed dynamically mesh vertices IMO but if you really want to do it shader side, you could try using 2 meshes and stencil shader.

Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html
Interesting video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7LQmJuoiBY